# Count number of rows in golang

Tags: mysql, go

I want to display the number of rows from database using Go. How do I display number of rows?

```
count, err := db.Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM main_table")
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: I need how many rows in table. Not check any user and password exists in database

Comment: People don't downvote questions because they don't know the answer. They downvote the question because it "does not show any research effort; it is unclear, or not useful". Blaming people who give you appropriate feedback is ridiculous.

Comment: In this case, a reasonable guess as to why you earned a downvote would probably be: As suggested in the first comment, you haven't explained the problem you're having. You showed one line of code, which appears to do what you want, without explaining how it falls short of your expectation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The query will return a row into the variable count. So the next you have to do is to read this row and assign the result into a new variable, using the function `Scan()`. This is how it works.

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM main_table")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer rows.Close()

var count int

for rows.Next() {   
    if err := rows.Scan(&count); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

fmt.Printf("Number of rows are %s\n", count)
```

The best option thought would be to use `QueryRow()` as you expect to read just one row. The code then will be.

```
var count int

err := db.QueryRow("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM main_table").Scan(&count)
switch {    
case err != nil:
    log.Fatal(err)
default:
    fmt.Printf("Number of rows are %s\n", count)
}
```

Comment: ok when i print count number on html template then it is looks 0015. Why two zero included before 15?

Comment: Without any code i can't really help you why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I signed up just to share this as my large datasets were slowing down the program with the constant appends.  I wanted to put the `rowcount` in the rows and figured that something like that must exist, just had to find it.

```
SELECT 
count(1) OVER(PARTITION BY domain_id) AS rowcount,
subscription_id,
domain_id,
...
FROM mytable 
WHERE domain_id = 2020
```

Never used this command before, but it will add the count of the result set that share this parameter.  Setting it to one of the query `WHERE`'s makes it the total rows.