# db.Exec() not returning correct RowsAffected() value in golang for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, go

I have written a Golang code to update the records in a table. In this, I have used `db.Exec(query)` function to execute the query and get the result back. I also want to check the no of rows affected by the query. For this, I have used result.RowsAffected(). But I am not getting the correct no of rows affected.

Below is my Golang Code

```
func updateTable(dbconnection *sql.DB, query string) (int64, error) {

    println("\n------------------Executing update Query---------------------")

    query = `UPDATE [IMBookingApp].[dbo].[User] 
                    SET Password='xyz'
                    WHERE UserId=2 OR UserId=22 OR UserId=23`    

    result, err := dbconnection.Exec(query)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error updating row: " + err.Error())
        errorMsg := errors.New("DATABASE ERROR - " + err.Error())
        return 0, errorMsg
    }

    RowsAffected, err := result.RowsAffected()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("RowsAffected Error", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Table updated successfully. Rows Affected:", RowsAffected)
    return RowsAffected, nil
}
```

The output I am getting is as below:-

```
    Table updated successfully. Rows Affected: 7
```

In the above SQL query, For the condition - `WHERE UserId=2 OR UserId=22 OR UserId=23` output is `Rows Affected: 7` However, I should be 3 or less than 3 because `UserId is a primary key`.

On SSMS, I am getting correct result for the same query - 
[image]

Similarly, for
 `WHERE UserId=2` output is `Rows Affected: 5`

`WHERE UserId=2 OR UserId=22` output is `Rows Affected: 6`

`WHERE UserId=2 OR UserId=22 OR UserId=23` output is `Rows Affected: 7`

`WHERE UserId=2 OR UserId=22 OR UserId=23 OR UserId=24` output is `Rows Affected: 8`

and "Rows Affected" goes on incrementing by 1 each time.

I have no idea what's going on. I would appreciate if anyone can help me point out the issue with the code.

***EDIT***

I have also tried to use `db.Query(query)` as below to find the affected rows, still, I am getting wrong no of affected rows.

```
rows, err := dbconnection.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var RowsAffected int
    for rows.Next() {
        RowsAffected += 1
    }

    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    print("RowsAffected:", RowsAffected)
```

Comment: Is the <mysql> tag really relevant here?

Comment: @jarlh I thought that the issue is not related to any specific database. Not sure though.

Comment: Related: Storing plaintext passwords? Using the same password for multiple identities? Just nope, nope, nope!

Comment: @SMor No, I am encrypting the passwords before storing it to the database. That is just the dummy data in the question.

Comment: I have tried another approach, still no luck. I added the details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think u're using SQL Server....

```
DECLARE @RowCount1 AS INT
 /* Your Update Query Will be Here.. */
 SELECT @RowCount1 = @@ROWCOUNT
 PRINT @RowCount1 --Here u will get Number affected by above Query...
```

Comment: Yes, I am using SQL Server. It's working in the SSMS. Do you know how can I use the same in the Golang code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49400284/count-number-of-rows-in-golang

Comment: https://blog.dotmaui.com/2017/10/24/golang-get-the-number-of-rows-affected-by-a-query/

Comment: I have tried the above solution still I am getting the same no of rows.

Comment: I have tried another similar solution still the same issue. I have added it to the question. Do you have any other suggestions for me?

Answer (score -1):

The go version has not implemented this feature yet.
Refer: https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-go/blob/master/result.go#L8

Comment: that specific library might not implement it but others like github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql do